# How to change date format from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYYMM in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause

I am trying to write a snowflake query that has a where condition to get between the (current_month + 6 months) and (current_month + 12 months).

The current format of the data is in YYYYMM format.

```
For example: 202307, 202308,202309
```

My query would look like this:

```
select business_month 
from table1 
where business_month between '202308' and '202406'
```

here is the SQL I am using:

```
select business_month 
from table1 
where business_month between ADD_MONTHS(current_date,6) and ADD_MONTHS(current_date,12)
```

The problem with this is that it is filtering by YYYY-MM-DD.

Is there a way to change the date format of the query above to be YYYYMM?

Answer (score 1):

Using `TO_DATE` -> `ADD_MONTHS` -> `TO_VARCHAR`:

```
select business_month 
from table1
where business_month between TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202308', 'YYYYMM'),6), 'YYYYMM')
                         and TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202406', 'YYYYMM'),12), 'YYYYMM');
```

---

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202308', 'YYYYMM'),6), 'YYYYMM'),
       TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202308', 'YYYYMM'),12), 'YYYYMM');
-- 202402   202408
```

or for current_date:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),'MONTH'),6), 'YYYYMM'),
       TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),'MONTH'),12), 'YYYYMM');
-- 202308    202402
```